# Flask Testing - why does coverage exclude import statements and decorators?

Tags: python, testing, flask, coverage.py

My tests clearly execute each function, and there are no unused imports either. Yet, according to the coverage report, 62% of the code was never executed in the following file:

[image]

Can someone please point out what I might be doing wrong?

Here's how I initialise the test suite and the coverage:

```
    cov = coverage(branch=True, omit=['website/*', 'run_test_suite.py'])
    cov.start()

    try:
        unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]])
    except:
        pass

    cov.stop()
    cov.save()

    print "\n\nCoverage Report:\n"
    cov.report()

    print "HTML version: " + os.path.join(BASEDIR, "tmp/coverage/index.html")
    cov.html_report(directory='tmp/coverage')
    cov.erase()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the third question in the [coverage.py FAQ](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/faq.html):

> Q: Why do the bodies of functions (or classes) show as executed, but
>   the def lines do not?
>
> This happens because coverage is started after the functions are
>   defined. The definition lines are executed without coverage
>   measurement, then coverage is started, then the function is called.
>   This means the body is measured, but the definition of the function
>   itself is not.
>
> To fix this, start coverage earlier. If you use the command line to
>   run your program with coverage, then your entire program will be
>   monitored. If you are using the API, you need to call coverage.start()
>   before importing the modules that define your functions.

The simplest thing to do is run you tests under coverage:

```
$ coverage run -m unittest discover
```

Your custom test script isn't doing much beyond what the coverage command line would do, it will be simpler just to use the command line.

Answer (score 7):

For excluding the imports statements, you can add the following lines to .coveragerc

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    # Ignore imports
    from
    import
```

but when I tried to add '@' for decorators, the source code within the scope of decorators was excluded. The coverage rate was wrong.
There may be some other ways to exclude decorators.